# jQuery looping through elements in two DIVs

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a script that loops through a list of DOM elements and manipulates each as it finds them. The problem I am running into is that I need to search two different divs for the same elements.

This is what I have so far

```
var elements = {
            1 : "h1",
            2 : "h2",
            3 : "h3",
            4 : "h4",
            5 : "p",
            6 : "li",
            7 : "a",
            8 : "td",
            9 : "span",
            10 : "img"
        }

        $.each(elements, function(key, val){
            if(val != "img") {
                if($(".t_content " + val + ":not([id^=element])"))
                    $(".t_content " + val + "[id^=element]").addClass('t_element');
            } else {
                $('.t_content, .t_component').find('img, div > img').addClass('t_element edit_img_area').removeClass('yellow');
                $(val).unwrap('a');
            }
        });
```

The div I am searching currently is `$(".t_content")` but I want to search `.t_content` and `.t_component`... I know you can search like this `$(".t_content, .t_component")` but I don't know how to incorporate that into this script.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you using a hash rather than an array? I would expect `elements` to look something like this instead: `["h1", "h2", "h3" ...]`

Comment: I have been working in Ruby so long now that I am used to writing Hashes... my apologies for this...

Comment: Could you clarify where exactly you want to search through `$(".t_content, .t_component")`? It's not really clear what you're trying to do, IMO. Is it this selector: `$(".t_content " + val + ":not([id^=element])")`? Can't you just do this: `$(".t_content " + val + ":not([id^=element]), ,t_component " + val + ":not([id^=element])")`?

Comment: @Matt, your suggestion is what I was looking for. I am still trying to grasp the second option in a jQuery selection and this forum is helping me a lot! Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
$("h1, h2, h3, h4 ...", $(".t_content, .t_component")).not("[id^=element]").addClass("t_element");
```

You can pass a second argument (context) to $() in jQuery which tells it to look within the context for the items you have in your selector. In your case, your second argument will be the two divs you want to search within: `$(".t_content, .t_component")`.

Comment: Thanks man! I am still trying to understand the context stuff with jQuery and this pretty much helped me understand a lot!

Comment: @dennis: just an FYI - Using a context is exactly equivalent (and a teeeeny bit slower than) using `.find()`, like this: `$(".t_content, .t_component").find("h1, h2, h3, h4 ...").not("[id^=element]")`. I personally find `.find()` to be more readable.

Comment: @Dennis Another FYI, using a context is actually slower, as Matt says, but it really is just a shorthand way of writing `.find('h1, h2...` and actually jQuery converts it TO a find in the core files. Just telling you because i personally like to know whats going on behind the scenes :)

Answer (score 2):

No need to loop, just select all the elements at once:

```
$('h1, h2, h3,... ').doSomething()
```

Comment: Thats what I was doing before... I was just trying to DRY my code up a little

Comment: or better yet: `$('h1, h2, h3,... ').each(function() { doSomething($(this)); })`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$elements = $('h1,h2,h3,h4,...');
$elements.whateverHere();
```

Or, another way, if you store your items just in a simple array you could do:

```
elements = ['h1','h2','h3'];
for(x in elements){
   if(elements[x] == 'h1'){/*Do something here*/}
}
```

In the first example im saving `$elements` for you to keep it more DRY since you can just reuse that one piece, and it'll be faster if you want to use it elsewhere since the elements are now cached in jQuery.

Here is how to loop through the JSON:

```
for (var key in element) {
  if (element.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + element[key]);
  }
}
```

I put it in an array though becuse it doesnt look like you need to see the key and value, you just want a, well, array of elements to check through.

Comment: Thanks Oscar! Is there a reason to do this in an array over a hash?

Comment: It could be either, but this is just less code/bytes to run through since you aren't manually setting the indexes (which from what it looks like you dont really need). You can also do a native loop through the JSON like this: (next comment)

Comment: Nevermind, added it to my post at the bottom! Let me know if that helps!